# SystemBadImageFormat Exception on IIS

Tags: .net, iis, badimageformatexception

Hi I have an  application running on iis with .net 4.7.2 and windows server 2016.Sometimes I got SystemBadImageFormat Exception: Bad Token error or SystemBadImageFormat Exception a valid typedef or typeref token is expected to follow a element type error.This error happens randomly ,and I cant find root cause of it.How can I troubleshoot and  fix this error?

Comment: If you only get this intermittently, my immediate suspicion would be a hardware issue.

Comment: I cant find root cause,How can I detect it?Do you have any idea.Yes I got it sometime ,not always

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/deploying-web-site-projects/processing-unhandled-exceptions-cs At least log those exceptions for further analysis.

Comment: try to enable 32-bit application pool in iis using application pool advance setting [image](https://imgur.com/a/WG3zbwb). also heck the iis logs and enable detail error message [image1](https://imgur.com/RohUIyG)

Comment: is thera a way to detect which dll is compiled 32bit or not?

Answer (score 1):

APM(Applicaiton Performance Monitoring)tool may be caused it.In my case ,apm tool caused clr error.